# How to model the relationship between Survey, Item, and different typologies of Answer

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, model

I'm coding an application to create surveys with Symfony3 and Doctrine. I would like to understand which is the best way to model the relation between the survey, items, and answers. A survey is composed by multiple items that have peculiar typologies of answer. For instance I could have the following typologies:

- AnswerChoice
- AnswerText
- AnswerRange
- etc..

Which is the best way to model this scenario with Doctrine?

I thought 2 possible solutions:

1. I create a single Answer object including every possible feature of the answers. The Item object should have a one-to-one relationship with this objects.

   - Pros: I have just one answer object
   - Cons: Confusing and against the single responsibility principle
2. I create a generic Item object containing a specific Answer object (AnswerChoice, AnswerText...) in a predefined class property. The Survey object should have a one-to-many relationship with Item that in turn will have a one-to-one relationship with a specific Answer object;

   - Pros: Nice solution but...
   - Cons: I need a property for each type of answer!

Could you please help me to choice the best solution? I have the feeling that I'm not facing well this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's inheritance. Actually [Doctrine handles inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) pretty well.

There are a few ways of implementing inheritance in Doctrine but I think, that in your case [Single Table Inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance) is what you're looking for.

That way you will be able to get a repository for parent (abstract) answer,but you'll get instances of actual child types in return.